Получить url всех вкладок открытого браузера
Дано: Открытый браузер "Firefox"
Необходимо: скопировать url всех открытых вкладок
Пробовал:
from icecream import ic
import pygetwindow as gw
import pyautogui
import time
import pyperclip

firefox_windows = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Mozilla Firefox')

for window in firefox_windows:
    window.activate()
    # pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'tab')
    time.sleep(1)
    tabs = pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle('Mozilla Firefox')
    for tab in tabs:
        tab.activate()
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'l')
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
        url = pyperclip.paste()
        ic(url)
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'tab')

Итог: копирутся три раза url только одной вкладки
Вопрос: в чем ошибка?
Какие еще библиотеке посоветуете использовать для решения этого вопроса?

Запустите диспетчер задач и удивитесь, что каждая вкладка это отдельный процесс и имеет свой дескриптор.

Благодарю, навели на мысль использовать psutil
